# Run Docker inside repository

Tags: git, docker

I have been asked to solve a challenge in C++ that works in Linux. I have developed my solution in my MacOS and have created a repo in Github. Moreover to ease the execution of my repo I have created a Dockerfile that configures all packages that need to be installed and so on.

My repo looks like:

```
UBIMET_Challenge

-- Dockerfile
-- Rest of .cpp files
-- build
```

My Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM rikorose/gcc-cmake
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libpng-dev
RUN git clone https://github.com/hect1995/UBIMET_Challenge.git
WORKDIR /UBIMET_Challenge
RUN mkdir build
WORKDIR build
RUN cmake ..
RUN make
RUN ./ubimet /UBIMET_Challenge/data/1706221600.29 output.csv
```

Is this a good way to present my work? It is for a job interview :)
Moreover, the last line of the Dockerfile should generate 2 files, what I do is after is:

```
docker build --tag <name_process> .
docker run -t -i <name_process> /bin/bash
```

Get the ID of the `/bin/bash` process and export it from the Docker to my local domain as:

```
docker cp <process_id>:/UBIMET_Challenge/build/heatmap0.png .
```

Where in this example I copy `heatmap0.png` to my local domain.

So my questions:

- Can I modify my Docker not to clone the repo as the Dockerfile itself is already inside the same repo?
- How would you make nicer the way to access the data generated by the container in your local domain (Like that files save automatically in the local domain)?

Comment: You can use [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).

Answer (score 1):

> Can I modify my Docker not to clone the repo as the Dockerfile itself is already inside the same repo?

YES.

You should generally avoid putting `git` commands in your Dockerfile.  There are three good reasons for this: the Dockerfile as you've shown it can't build anything other than committed changes to `master` (can't build an image for integration testing of a proposed change; can't build an image from a branch); because of Docker layer caching, if you update the repository, the image won't actually get rebuild; and if the repository is private, correctly managing the credentials (and not leaking them into the final image) is tricky.

> How would you make nicer the way to access the data generated by the container in your local domain (Like that files save automatically in the local domain)?

I wouldn't use Docker for this case and would run the process directly on the host.  Since the major goal of your program is to write a file to the local system, you actively don't want Docker's filesystem isolation, and you're not taking advantage of any of Docker's other networking features or planning to run this in a clustered environment.

You might look at tools like Vagrant for the specific workflow you've set up here.  Even if you configure it to be backed by Docker, it's a little more purpose-designed for having only an alternate-OS build environment.

> `docker run -t -i <name_process> /bin/bash`

Generally you should think of a container as a wrapper around a single process.  In the same way that you're not going to open up a shell in your Web browser and `cp` files out of it, this isn't a really convenient way to work with Docker.

Instead of `RUN`ning the program in the Dockerfile, you can make it the default `CMD` when the image is run.  I might set up:

```sh
...
RUN make

WORKDIR /UBIMET_Challenge
RUN mkdir output
CMD ["./build/ubimet", "./data/1706221600.29", "./output/output.csv"]
```

Then when you run the container you need to [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) a directory over the `output` directory

```
docker run --rm -v $PWD:/UBIMET_Challenge/output <image_name>
```

and the result file will be put there.

Comment: what is <image_name>?

Comment: Moreover, what I want is to get an isolated environment to prove that my project works no matter in which environment they are testing it

Comment: It's the name of the image that you passed to the `docker build -t` option; you called it `<name_process>` in the question, but "process" isn't really a Docker term.